# Ignoring an Insert Using a Trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with three tables User(userID, Firstname, LastName), Movies(MovieID, MovieName), and UserMovies(MovieID, userID). I also have a trigger in the User table that I would like to have run After Insert that determines if the supplied userID is already existing. If the supplied userID exists in the table, how do I go about ignoring the insert that triggered the trigger and began manipulating the Movies table (my next INSERT command)? I tried using RETURN

if exists(select insert.userID FROM inserted)
return

but that's not working for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict data insertion based on some condition, you should do it in the `before trigger`. Here, check to see if the user_id already exists. If it does, then you can restrict inserting that data in your table by rolling back the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Raise an exception in your trigger function.

```
RAISERROR ('Error Text', 11, 1);
```

I don't know of another way to "ignore" an insert in a trigger function.  Since the function was triggered by an INSERT command, the INSERT should either happen or an error should occur.

Another way to do this would be to write a stored procedure that checks for your condition before attempting the INSERT.